# how to remove the borders in JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing

i was able to remove the title bar from the `JInternalFrame` but i don't know how to remove the borders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove the border simply call `frame.setBorder(null);`

Any border that is `null` is simply not shown.

Answer (score 1):

To remove all borders, simply call:

```
this.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```