# Can't remove border of JInternalFrame | Nimbus L&F

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, nimbus

I've already done research on how to make a `JInternalFrame` show only its content without the borders.

Remove the top title bar:
[hiding title bar of JInternalFrame? -java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218608/hiding-title-bar-of-jinternalframe-java)

Remove the surrounding borders:
[how to remove the borders in JInternalFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620970/how-to-remove-the-borders-in-jinternalframe)

Everything works smoothly, until I tested my work with Numbus UI, I could get the title bar off, but the surrounding borders are stuck there:

[image]

The expected result (which works on other L&Fs) should be:

[image]

I assume there's some UI related setting that should solve it (`UIDefaults`, or `comp.putClientProperty()`); but I can't figure what it is.

Comment: isn't easier to use undecorated JDialog or JWindow (used for accordion/docking)

Comment: @mKorbel I'm more comfortable with using lightweight components.

Comment: This way i don't have to take care of parent frame move, iconify etc. events.

Comment: Another issue: With Windows Aero when a `JFrame` is deiconified it will show an animation, but making the [previously] hidden window visible [again], will show instantly; this looks awkard. `JInternalFrame` nicely solves it, so my docking goes along with the animation.

Answer (score 0):

With trial and error, I found a clean but still incomplete solution.

All I have to do is change the UI of the `JInternalFrame` to just any other.
The new UI will not do any actual rendering, since I removed the title-bar and borders.

This solution is incomplete,
 **DO NOT CALL** anywhere in your code:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI();
```

This will cause the internal frame to reset back to the default UI.

---

**EDIT:** 
Finally found a solution to the above reset problem. Just prevent Swing from installing any other than my custom set UI.

Using a subclass of `JInternalFrame`:

```
@Override
public void updateUI() {
        LookAndFeel laf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }

        super.updateUI();

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
    }
```

This effectively ignores any change to set the UI, but I'm not happy with it. It resetsthe whole Look and Feel, and may cause race conditions which may cause unwanted LaF settings.

I'm still on the search for a solution, setting only this component to Metal.